# Android: Shader behave different in 'onDraw(canvas)' and 'new Canvas(bitmap)'

Tags: android

I am trying to create a reflection shadow and found an issue.

Please find the below code in my custom view:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //prepare
    canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
    Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

    //First Column
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0, new Paint());

    //2nd Column
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, source.getWidth(), 0, new Paint());

    //Reflection
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.preScale(1.0f, -1.0f);
    matrix.postTranslate(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight()*2);
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, matrix, new Paint());

    Paint paint2 = new Paint();
    LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(
            source.getWidth()*3/2, 
            source.getHeight(),
            source.getWidth()*3/2,
            source.getHeight()*2,
            0x7FFFFFFF, 0x00FFFFFF, TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint2.setShader(shader);
    paint2.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
            android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    canvas.drawRect(
            source.getWidth(), 
            source.getHeight(),
            source.getWidth()*2,
            source.getHeight()*2,
            paint2);

    //3rd Column
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight()*2, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas2.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0,  new Paint());
    matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.preScale(1.0f, -1.0f);
    matrix.postTranslate(0, source.getHeight()*2);
    canvas2.drawBitmap(source, matrix, new Paint());


    paint2 = new Paint();
    shader = new LinearGradient(
            source.getWidth()*1/2, 
            source.getHeight(),
            source.getWidth()*1/2,
            source.getHeight()*2,
            0x7FFFFFFF, 0x00FFFFFF, TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint2.setShader(shader);
    paint2.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
            android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    canvas2.drawRect(
            0, 
            source.getHeight(),
            source.getWidth(),
            source.getHeight()*2,
            paint2);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, source.getWidth()*2,0, new Paint());
}
```

I am doing same in canvas (which I got from `onDraw(canvas)`) and canvas2 (which created using `new Canvas(bitmap)`)

But, both drawing different shader effect as follows:
[image: different shader effect]

Why are the shader effects different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the black rectangle in the second column:

PorterDuff.MODE.DST_IN is defined as [Sa*Da, Sa*Dc]. Since the destination pixels are a constant opaque grey (Da=1) the alpha channel of the result will be set to the alpha channel from your linear gradient, which ranges from 0.5 to 1.

And there is your problem right there... in the second column you are setting pixels of your Window canvas partially transparent. What shows through from underneath? The window background, which is still the default black.

In the 3rd column you are drawing to an offscreen bitmap first, and then drawing the partially-transparent offscreen bitmap to the Window canvas afterwards. This works because the incoming pixels (from the offscreen bitmap) do not completely replace the pixels already present but are blended with the destination buffer (in PorterDuff terms I think it's equivalent to SRC_ATOP).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But still I am not clear about the source and destination, The destination is not the state of the canvas before the drawRect() call (I mean, an canvas with image drawn on top of that). Rather the state when it was created. I changed the 3rd column source code as   //3rd Column
  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight()*2, Config.RGB_565);
  bitmap.eraseColor(Color.GRAY); then got same as 2nd column. It looks we couldn't change the canvas from onDraw(canvas) to behave as off-screen bitmap canvas?

Comment: If you use Config.RGB_565 you are throwing away the alpha channel of the offscreen bitmap, so it cannot be blended when drawn to the window canvas. It will simply replace the destination pixels.